# Changing calendar display

Tags: calendar

When I first got my Android it gave me the monthly view of my calendar. It has switched to daily agenda. ARGH!  How do I switch it back to weekly or monthly view?

Answer (score 4):

Hit the menu button.

It should then bring up the day/week/month view options.